# IIS install failed because "the server that you specified requires a restart" constant loop

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012

I have a machine running Windows Server 2012 Datacentre and have been having problems re-installing IIS.  It had been installed previously but could not properly locate the .NET central configuration so I tried a re-install.  The uninstall went fine although when re-installing (after a reboot) I was presented with the error:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the server that you specified requires a restart
```

At first I tried a restart but I still got this error afterwards.  I searched the Internet and have tried several options including:

- Add **NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES** to the **Log on as a service** privilege in Group Policy - this was already set on my machine
- Explicitly add **MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID** to the **Log on as a service** privilege in Group Policy - this user/service could not be found and could therefore not be added
- Install Windows Internal Database - the install failed alongside IIS

What is odd is IIS is not installed but it still appears as a snap-in in the Computer Management MMC but not in Server Manager.

Is there anything else I can try other than a full Windows re-install and reset?  I can run IIS on a VM on top of this server but the fact I have problems configuring server roles and features concerns me as it is effectively a faulty instance at present.

The server has the Hyper-V role enabled and Visual Studio 2015 Community and SQL Server 2014 Enterprise installed.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any files in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv? If so, try moving them to another temp folder during the reinstall. It should be empty if IIS isn't installed.

Also, can you install other applications? You mentioned that Windows Internal Database wouldn't install, so this suggests that the issue may be with the Windows installer rather than IIS itself.

Does Event Viewer have any clues, with either a timestamp right after the last reboot or during the attempted install?

Comment: Many thanks for your response, however, I had performed a full server reinstall by the time you wrote this.  :(  I am reorganising application distribution and will be moving IIS onto a Hyper-V VM (it's not a critical instance).  If the issue ever comes up again I shall try this method though.

Comment: @BWHazel That sounds good. Thanks for the update. All the best with it.